# Adding HTC Widgets to AppWidgetPicker Intent

Tags: android, android-appwidget, homescreen, htc-android

I am writing a homescreen replacement App. I'd like to allow users the same selection of Widgets that are available on the HTC Sense Homescreen on HTC phones.

Is there documentation anywhere of the ComponentName details required to be added to the Intent to show the HTC Settings option in the Widgets popup list?

The info needed is Component Name, Icon and name String.

Comment: I have given up on this. The HTC rosie widgets are not normail widgets but part of the home screen App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not feasible. The HTC Rosie Widgets are not Android Platform Widgets and therefore cannot be accessed outside of the Rosie APK. .